# Have any idea how to install the Tile mill in RHEL 5 OS?

Tags: dictionary, gis, rhel5, tilemill

hi team am trying to install the TileMill in RHEL 5 , have any idea what all are the sub packages we need to install  ? i have tied with as per the procedure in Tile mill and am getting struck with required components of the sub packages . please Sugest if any one already done the Tile mill with Rhel ?

Answer (score 0):

We'd recommend following the [building from source instructions](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/source/), and replacing the `apt-get` calls with calls from your choice of package manager.